# Why does CONTAINS not find matches at the end of the string?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) which searches a table for anything matching a `@Keywords` parameter that I pass in. It was too slow using `LIKE` as the table has 155,000 rows, so I created a fulltext catalog and switched to using `CONTAINS` instead. I am not very familiar with this feature, but after researching it seemed all I needed to do was process the user's choice of words with:

```
SET @Keywords = '"' + @Keywords + '*"'
```

Adding the double quotes and asterisk worked well until someone discovered they had no results when searching for a string they knew definitely existed. It seems that the `*` is stopping `CONTAINS` from finding rows where the `@Keywords` are right at the very end of the string.

**Analysis with very simple t-SQL:**

```
--first I prove that I can find the one row which the user was searching for
--this column is a NVARCHAR(200)
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE Headline = '1120 days at sea and still sailing' --1 row returned (OK)
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE Headline LIKE '1120 days at sea and still sailing%' --1 row returned (OK)

--using the full headline
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"1120 days at sea and still sailing*"') --no rows, just like my proc (WRONG)
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"1120 days at sea and still sailing"') --1 row returned if asterisk omitted (OK)

--using part of the headline so we don't touch the end of the
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"days at sea and still"') --lots of rows, since it is anything with 'days' and then 'sea' present (NOT USEFUL)
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"days at sea and still*"') --no rows (WRONG)
```

I note that `CONTAINS` considers *at/and/still* to be 'noise' words and ignores them. Fair enough. The word *sailing* is the troublesome one at the end of the string.

**My question:**

How should I modify the incoming keywords to make sure than `CONTAINS` can find results regardless of the position of the string of keywords within the column value?

Answer (score 5):

**This has to do with how stoplist (or noise words) is/are treated when adding the asterix (*) in combination with `CONTAINS()`.**

A longer explanation on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035291/sql-server-full-text-search-contains-not-working-as-expected).

**In short: Default <> Prefix searching**

By default, when using the `SYSTEM` stoplist some words are not indexed and classified as stoplist words.

When adding the * + `CONTAINS()`they are not seen as stoplist words, and the exact phrase has to match.
But when using the default `SYSTEM` stoplist these 'stoplist words' are not added to the index, resulting in no matches found.

---

**Question**

> Are you saying that the intended behaviour, when an asterisk is
>   present, is to return zero matches for a user who includes a noise
>   word? This seems surprising, when you consider what most humans are
>   likely to type!

**Prefix matching in combination with contains from microsoft docs**

> Specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with the specified
>   text. Enclose a prefix term in double quotation marks ("") and add an
>   asterisk (*) before the ending quotation mark, so that all text
>   starting with the simple term specified before the asterisk is matched

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)

Keywords here are:

> so that all text
>   starting with the simple term specified before the asterisk is matched

Meaning that we have to have precise matches when using prefix matching and `CONTAINS()`.

---

**Workaround #1 Disabling the stoplist**

One workaround for this would be disabling the 'stoplist'

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON News
SET STOPLIST OFF;
```

You do have to know that this will increase the words stored in the fulltext index, as the words 'and', 'or', 'still', ... are added to the index.

*Performance might suffer from disabling the stoplist.*

**To reenable the system stoplist**

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON News
SET STOPLIST SYSTEM;
```

*Alternatively, you could create your own stoplist*

**Testing this on your query:**

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON News
SET STOPLIST OFF;
INSERT INTO News(Headline)
VALUES('1120 days at sea and still sailing')

INSERT INTO News(Headline)
VALUES('zzz 1120 days at sea and still sailing')

SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"days at sea and still*"')
```

**Result**

```
id  Headline
1   1120 days at sea and still sailing
2   zzz 1120 days at sea and still sailing
```

*For other workarounds you could look into using `CONTAINS()` or `FREETEXT()` without prefix matching, or prefix matching + `CONTAINS()` with one (non noise) word to get more accurate results*

---

**In your case, enbling `transform noise words` does not seem to work with prefix-matching**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Again due to how prefix matching + contains works.

```
SELECT * FROM News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"1120 days at sea and still sailing*"')
```

-- No results

---

**Inside the fulltext index (with stoplist = system).**

```
SELECT display_term,column_id,document_count
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords(DB_ID('MNGDB'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.News'));
```

**result**

```
display_term    column_id   document_count
1120                 2           2
days                 2           2
nn1120               2           2
sailing              2           2
sea                  2           2
zzz                  2           1
END OF FILE          2           2
```

*'Still','at','and' are filtered out, when disabling the stoplist they will be added to the index*

**Testing without stopwords**

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON News
SET STOPLIST SYSTEM;

INSERT INTO dbo.News
VALUES('days sea sailing')
SELECT * FROM dbo.News 
WHERE CONTAINS(Headline, '"days sea sailing*"') 

id  Headline
4   days sea sailing
```

**More on the asterix**

> The presence of the asterisk enables the prefix-matching mode...
>   If a phrase is provided, matches are detected if the column contains
>   all the specified words with zero or more other characters following
>   the final word

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-sql-wildcards)

Comment: Are you saying that the intended behaviour, when an asterisk is present, is to return zero matches for a user who includes a noise word?  This seems surprising, when you consider what most humans are likely to type!

Comment: @MagnusSmith I believe so, due to how prefix matching in combination with contains works

Answer (score 0):

> How should I modify the incoming keywords to make sure than CONTAINS
>   can find results regardless of the position of the string of keywords
>   within the column value?

I think you have to code for it.

1. If search string contain single word then use wildcard.
2. Catch those `StopList` words in your application,check if search string contain any of those `StopList`then do NOT use wildCard.

   where contains(documentsummary,'"guidlines are provided"')
3. If search string has more than one word and it do not contain any `StopList` words then do  use wildCard.

   where contains(documentsummary,'"cycle bicyle*"')

Create custom table and copy the system `Stopwords` in it as well as you can add your own.

```
Select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords
where language_id=1033
```

IMO, `Set StopList Off` is not bad idea.Because I would like to find all document that has `Exact Phrase`  `'"guidlines are provided*"'` any where without using `Like` Operator

There should be option for User to choose criteria like "`Exact Phrase`","`Similar Phrase`" ,"use `OR`" ,"use `And`" etc.So depending upon these condition you can write for it.

I mean to say that this is why there are so many search option are there in [FULLTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) search AND [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql).

Answer (score -1):

this query can help to fixed the issue contains with 1 char

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON TableName SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435602/sql-2008-turn-off-stop-words-for-full-text-search-query/8436411#8436411